# Using JButton to change background color in JFrame with OOP

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

Im trying to learn to use Jframes in Java and i want to start easy. I wanted to make a JFrame with buttons that have different usage. The one button should change the background color of the frame but it does nothing
(i left the imports out but i have them in my code)

```
public class Main{
    static MyFrame frame = new MyFrame("Test");;
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        MyButton change = new MyButton("Change Color", "changeColor");
        MyButton exit = new MyButton("Exit", "exit");

        frame.setSize(500, 250);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(change);
        frame.add(exit);
    }
}
```

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    MyFrame(String title){
        super(title);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

```
public class MyButton extends JButton implements ActionListener{
    String use;
    
    MyButton(String title, String use){
        super(title);
        this.use = use;
        addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(use.equals("exit")){
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(use.equals("changeColor")){
            Main.frame.setBackground(Color.blue);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To stand any chance of working, that would have to be something more like `Main.frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);` A button shouldn't be its own `ActionListener` btw - that's simply an anti-pattern

Answer (score 0):

- Don't extend `JFrame`.
- Do extend `JPanel` and use that to hold components, etc.
- Also note that you do not need to make all the classes public. Only the one that contains the `static main` entry point is required.  For small programs like this, just add classes without any access level modifiers (public, private,etc) right after the main public class.  It can make it easier to debug and modify.  The down side is for large programs, you will needlessly compile everything.   In that case use separate class files.

Here is an example which uses a map to hold the Color name and Color object for creating the JButton and its actionListener.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ChangeColor extends JPanel {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Map<String, Color> colors = Map.of("RED", Color.RED, "BLUE", Color.BLUE,
            "MAGENTA", Color.MAGENTA);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new ChangeColor().start());
    }

    public void start() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center on screen
        for (Entry<String, Color> e : colors.entrySet()) {
            add(createButton(e));  // add button to JPanel
        }
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }

    public JButton createButton(Entry<String, Color> entry) {
        JButton b = new JButton(entry.getKey()); // set button name
        b.addActionListener((ae) -> {
            setBackground(entry.getValue());  // set the background color
            repaint();
        });
        return b;
    }

}
```

Comment: Care to put a little logic about the extend JFrame vs JPanel? I would like to be educated on the subject.

Comment: Normally when one extends a class, they do it to override method(s) to add/or change functionality.   In `JPanel`, `paintComponent()` is very often overridden .  Here I overrode `getPreferredSize()` although I could have used `setPreferredSize()` which may lead to side effects in certain uses.   With `JFrame`, I have never had to override anything so I just create an instance of it.  The tutorials will show examples of `JFrame` being extended but those examples were written over a decade ago and current consensus among experienced Java developers is that it is not a good technique to do so.

Comment: Well, as a over a decade ago(++) programmer, I was doing this.  Never much gave it much thought, it was how you did it.  I have been going through the StackOverflow  extends JFrame questions and they agree with you.  So it looks I need to change my ways. Thanks

Comment: Also, using `JPanel` is easy to size to the Frame.   If you set the size of  `JFrame` it will include the borders.  So your drawing window will be somewhat smaller.  By using `JPanel` and setting the size, `JFrame` will be sized properly to hold the exact size of the JPanel.  Using frame.pack() will invoke the layout managers to position their components accordingly.  For more on this and other topics just search StackOverflow as some of these topics may be answered in more depth.